# Document manager for paperless office

Tags: windows, backup, document-management, document-indexing

In my effort to reduce my life's clutter, I've bought a scanner, and scanned the thousands of paper documents scattered around my house.

To make this worthwhile I need a software which will enable me to save all these documents securely, as well as allow me to find the ones I need when I need them.

I need a program which can:

- Store and index thousands of documents (PDF, PNG, etc. either OCRed or not)
- Be secure (some of those documents are very private - bank statements, etc.) - meaning client side encryption.
- Provide some back-up solution (for the possibility of my PC frying with all my paper history...)
- Allow for day-to-day management and addition of new documents
- Store document's date (which should be editable, since it might not be the date it was scanned/inserted to the system)
- Have some cloud features (search anywhere) - advantage

I'm using a Windows 7 machine.

**Note**

Although I've posted the answer of what *I* use as a solution, I am very interested to hear of other solutions, as mine is a little convoluted... Anyone?

Comment: This is for the paper in the home clutter - mine, and still most people's home computer is Windows - hence the requirement. Web-apps are allowed, though I would be interested to see how they can uphold the security requirement...

Answer (score 8):

Currently I use [Evernote](https://evernote.com) to store and index all my documents.

**How does it match the requirements?**

- *Store and index thousands of documents*: that's its main usecase
- *Allow for day-to-day management*: very easily add and tag documents
- *Store document's date*: in Evernote, you can easily edit an entry's `Created at` field, which elegantly solves the initial porting problem.
- *Cloud features*: by default all documents are available online.

**Where it falls short**

- *Be secure - client side encryption*: [Evernote does not provide client side encryption](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/36764-encrypt-a-whole-notebook/page-3). Since this is very critical for me, I use Evernote's private notebook feature for my scanned documents. This of course negates the *backup* feature of Evernote...
- *Provide backup solution*: Since I'm not using Evernote's cloud feature, I need to provide my own backup solution. For that I use [CrashPlan Pro](http://www.code42.com/crashplan/), with which I backup Evernote's database file (`%PROGRAM_DATA%/Evernote/Databases`). CrashPlan uses client-encryption, and incremental change support, so it is very well fitted for this need.

Here are my experiences at [scanning](http://uri.agassi.co.il/2012/09/going-paperless.html), [backing up](http://uri.agassi.co.il/2012/09/going-paperless-backing-up.html) and [indexing](http://uri.agassi.co.il/2012/09/going-paperless-using-evernote.html) my paperless office.

I would like to know if there is a more stream-lined solution out there, which does not require me to weave two programs to fit all my needs...

Comment: I'm in the same position as you are and looking for exactly for the same software / solution. Evernote seems like _a_ solution, but like you described there are some downsides. One year after your original post, have you found something better / more suited?

Comment: @Ratnanil - I have still not found a better solution, though I still think my current solution is not ideal. I'll be very glad to see any new posts on this subject here or elsewhere... How are you handling this situation?

Comment: At the moment, I'm doing it in the worst manner possible: With dropbox. This "solution" has the benefit of being cloud based, cross plattform and it comes along with some backup features. The main downside is the lack of the "tag"-capability. In addition, I seriously question the secureness (considering how easy it is to create a public link to any file stored within the dropbox). I'd like to reanimate your question, how would I best go about this? Is rephrasing it ok?

Comment: @Ratnanil - the canonical way to do that here is using [bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: I'm still unsure of how my *perfect* solution would look like. I'm actually looking into evernote business. Which plan are you using?

Comment: @Ratnanil - I'm using the free tier, as the bulk of the features I need is the offline notebook (since evernote still does not support encrypted notebooks) - the paid version adds nothing that I need.

Comment: @Uri Agassi, I was wondering if you managed to change your system or kept with Evernote? Regarding security, today there is an add-on which can encrypt notebooks in both Evernote and OneOnte called "Saferoom", have you seen it or are using it? Cheers!

Comment: @TVDN - I still use Evernote, though I would still like to have serious alternatives to consider (haven't found any that fits my requirements). Regarding "saferoom" - I was not aware of it, so I will check it out, but from my initial look, it seems that it encrypts only the note's contents, so the metadata (title, tags) are still cleartext - and that's valuable data I'd like to keep secure...

Comment: That is too bad. I am pretty much in the same situation. The file size limit is not helping me with evernote, and the path size limit is not helping with windows. I am attempting with Microsoft Access however the file size limit is not working either. My next attempt will be to use XAMPP or similar to run local server and possibly use logicalDOC or similar. I would much prefer just a local installation than a web interface though.

Comment: Tell me if you find an interesting alternative!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [paperless-ngx](https://docs.paperless-ngx.com/).

- can store and index PDF and other document formats (with the help of OCR)
- it's open source
- provides a tag mechanism so you can look for certain documents
- has a fancy web interface and comes also with support for mobile devices

I'm not sure, though, whether it provides the required security.

Also it seems lacking the cloud functionality.