# Simple versioning for plain-text documents (Linux)

Tags: gratis, linux, document-management, version-control, plain-text

I would like to identify a simple, FOSS version control system for plain text documents.

For more complex (academic) writing, I happily use LibreOffice. But increasingly I find it convenient to write more simple documents (reports, presentations, lectures, note-taking, whatever) in Markdown, usually using [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext).

My goal now is to manage versions of these documents. A scenario might be: drafting a presentation --> "finished" version delivered at Event A --> now redrafted --> delivered at Event B --> now occasion C comes along, for which the Event A version is the better one --> pulled and drafted for Event C.

So, my requirements are:

- version control (essential, obviously!)
- Ubuntu/Mint friendly (PPA would be great)
- easy tagging/commenting/labelling of "commits"
- simple tag/label browsing
- simple tag/label searching
- simple "recovery" of previous versions
- possibility of doing diffs
- possibility of syncing to different machines
- simple directory structure/hierarchy for docs

One obvious solution that I'm aware of would be to use [Git to manage the version control](https://maugre.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/using-git-for-version-control-with-plaintext-student-notes/) (and a number of other write-ups on around the web). I'm not *wholly* averse, and have used Github casually both from Windows and Linux (Ubuntu, Mint) for some years. **But** the key word there is "**casually**" -- and it seems a bit of a sledgehammer-to-nut scenario.

(I have also seen the question about a "[Document manager for paperless office](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/736/435)", but that appears to go well beyond my needs.)

There may well be other options out there, and certainly there will be tools I have never heard of. Grateful for any help with this one.

Comment: This has all the elements of a good question. Yet I find it a bit problematic, because to me the answer is: yes, you want a distributed versioning system, and any of the common ones will do. Pick any of Bazaar, Git, Mercurial or even the less common ones. I don't see a differentiating factor.

Comment: Yes - I think that's why I've been hesitant to post (been sitting on this a few days). For me, the key issue is *how* those tasks are accomplished. Perhaps this relates to @Caleb's questions about simple GUIs for git. So I suppose the "differentiating factor" is the ease-of-use, "simplicity" in commenting a commit, pulling a particular version, seeing a "diff" between given versions, etc. Does that get us anywhere?

Comment: "ease of use" is a difficult requirement, because whether a product meets that requirement is mostly opinion.  I think you need to make the case that a conventional versioning system won't do the job, before you ask for something else.

Comment: What's wrong with RCS/CVS?

Comment: @DVK - if I knew what "RCS/CVS" was, I would be in a better position to answer that question. ;) (And yes, I've heard of "Google"!)

Comment: @IraBaxter - "you need to make the case that a conventional versioning system won't do the job" - why? Doesn't that make some assumptions about either my personal skill set or inclinations? If there something in the "request spec" I've outlined that's a problem, do tell. But I'm not sure why I should have to demonstrate that "a conventional versioning system won't do the job": in my post I make clear that it *can*, in fact, but that I'm still interested to know what other options are available. Should that be problematic? (Genuine question - not rhetorical!)

Comment: @David: Because otherwise the answer to this question is just the list of standard version control systems, at which point your question should be "What version control systems exist (for storing any kind of document)?".   That question might be worth answering in that form, but would seem pointless to answer for special cases covered by the general case.

Comment: @Davïd I think you should make clearer what you mean by "ease of use"; For example: I find the unix command shell to be totally intuitive and easy to use. I would instantly recommend git for this job because the CLI is so practical. I'm quite certain your opinion will differ but I have no possibility to understand whats "easy" to you, because you didn't write it. A few hints: GUI or CLI? Local or Network based? If GUI: express what you like (post examples on "easy" guis).

Comment: The two questions I asked about newbie interfaces should not scare you off! Those are aimed at people who can't even open a terminal, would have no idea what markdown or markup is, and do not actually need the version control features so much as they have to use the push feature as a replacement for uploading via FTP.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Yes, you should use `git`*.**

Now let me explain why. Given the current (rather nebulous) set of criteria in your question the answer seems fairly obvious. If you knew any more, you wouldn't even be asking this question. You have already brought yourself to the edge of the cliff, now you just need coaxing to make the jump.

<sub>* Or Fossil, Mercurial, Darcs, Bazaar, or other DVCS depending on the front end tooling you prefer, to be explained.</sub>

#### The current scene and some history:

There are basically three kinds of version control systems: *distributed*, *ham-fisted*, and *tapped-out*. Allow me to expand on that technical terminology and how each came to be and would apply to your situation.

- *ham-fisted*

  Notable entries*: CVS, Subversion.

  Before DVCS systems took the world by storm, there were VCS systems. These could be characterized by a central repository/server and a star pattern of user-workspaces/clients. These were an indispensably valuable tool for keeping a team of programmers on the same page and even adapted themselves to other uses. A single programmer could work from multiple systems and play around with branches and tags. They saved many a day. But they were inherently clumsy. **They make some simple tasks harder**. First there was the overhead of setting them up, the need for a server and specific protocols to connect them. Then there was the pain of dealing with those times you did something wrong. Suffice it to say these would get the job done for your use case but would introduce trade offs making life more complicated.
- *tapped-out*

  Notable entry: RCS.

  For when a "full blown" system involving servers and clients and authentication and all that jazz was too much to swallow, it was possible to use a pared down system that lived in its own little bubble. RCS did this by eschewing the idea of a repository and just versioning one file at a time. You had `file.txt` and sitting right next to it a `file.txt,v` that had the version history. You could instantiate it easily on a per-file basis and use a handful of simple tools to work with diffs, roll back time, etc.

  Now before you say, "Ah ha, that's just what I was looking for!", please read on because this is not the easiest or recommended way to do this any more. **Easy entry came at the cost of a low operational ceiling** that is pretty much guaranteed to cramp your style sooner or later.
- *distributed*

  At some point a bunch of smart programmers decided they had had enough of the pain and said, "We are going to eat cake and have it too." Amazingly, they succeed and distributed version control systems were born. These systems combine the best of both worlds—complete version history sitting on your local system right next to the original files plus the ability to share your history and interact with that of other remote repositories. It turns out there are no serious technical disadvantages to doing this.

  The most significant barrier for some shops turned out to be the flexibility. Because the systems don't impose arbitrary restrictions on the way you work, it is sometimes painful to migrate from a system that forced you to have a certain workflow. Suddenly you have to think a little bit about how you want your system to work. Many things that used to be required (central node that always has everybody's latest stuff) became a matter convention to be used only when desired but you have to sit down and say, "This is how we are going to use this tool."

So lets sit down and say how *you* would use this tool.

For the purposes of this answer I am going to stick to git because it is one of the most widely adopted systems. It is easy to install on most any system (on the off chance it isn't installed already) and there is a wide range of documentation available covering almost any use case. It is also extensible and recognized by many third party systems, etc. That being said it is not necessarily inherently better that its nearest competition, Bazaar or Mercurial.

- If you live in an Ubuntu ecosystem, you might want to give Bazaar a look because Canonical uses it for everything and it will integrate well with your environment. Their [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) service is similar to Github, but tailored to Ubuntu software development. If you plan to play in that ecosystem, consider learning `bzr` instead of git so that one tool works for both your personal world and the ecosystem you participate in. If you don't work on projects coordinated on launchpad, I would suggest using git.
- If any of your colleagues is big into Mercurial, you might want to look into using it. It's a very capable DVCS with some advantages over Git. It's frequently alleged to be faster for some operations due to a more streamlined data flow. The tooling is all wrapped into a single binary rather than being clobbered together from a bunch of separate (and sometimes redundant) tools like Git is. It it extensible using Python bindings and it's possible to built external systems that integrate very tightly with it. The paradigm is similar enough to Git that once you learn it you'll also be able  to blunder your way around a git repository. In the end however git is the most popular player in the field right now and sticking with it will give you readier access to help when you need it.

<sub>* My apologies to all the VCS systems not named. CVSNT, CA, CC,  Perforce, Plastic, PVCS, Star, SVK, Vault, Vesta, VSS and a litany of others. Your names <strike>will never be forgotten</strike> are already just a memory.</sub>

#### How `git` fits your use case:

You mentioned having used Github a little. That's great, but you need to keep in mind that **Github is not git**. It is a common miss-perception that what they are offering is a free way to get into the system by hosting your repositories for you. In reality what they offer is a layer built out on top of git that is part social-networking and part project-management. This is a great thing for the open-source community. Instead of trying to be an alternative system and fighting the market, they have brilliantly leveraged a good tool and carved out a market providing a value added service for corporations and serving the community at the same time. But Github is not git.

Git can, in fact, be used in a much simpler fashion.

Similar to RCS, git stores the version information locally right next to your content. The notable difference out of the gate is that it does this on a per directory basis rather than a per file basis.

- RCS:

  ```
    file1.txt
    file1.txt,v
    file2.txt
    file2.txt,v
  ```

  The `,v` file for each file keeps a running list of the file history, storing the delta between each consecutive version.
- git:

  ```
     directory
     + file1.txt
     + file2.txt
     + .git
       + glob1
       + glob2
  ```

  The stuff in the .git folder actually has funky names and is kind of complicated, but you don't need to know about it. Conceptually all it is doing is storing the differences between versions of stuff it your directory. Basically each glob is an image of what your directory looked like at the time of each commit. A lot of fancy math keeps the overhead down so that only the delta data is saved.

Now this may be sounding complex already, but you really don't need to know any of that. The tool-set keeps track of all the fancy stuff for you. The basic usage in very bit as easy as RCS but gives you room to grow down the road.

Getting started would go something like this:

```
# Change to the directory that has files you want to version.
cd ~/pathto/yourtextfiles

# Initialize git to keep track of that folder
git init
```

Done. No servers needed. Just you and your version controlled files. Except you don't have any files under surveillance yet so git isn't actually watching anything. Git is not greedy in the sense that it does not keep track of everything in a folder, only the specific things you tell it to. So the next step is to tell it what files you want to track.

```
# Add some files to the system, assuming these already exist the your dir
git add file1.txt file2.txt

# Commit the changes you just made
git commit -m "initial add"
```

Note that unlike most systems, this is a two step process. Before you commit things and stuff them in the repository as a new version, you have to 'stage' them. Not every change you make to your working directory is automatically assumed to be something you want to save to with each commit. Maybe you changed two files but only want to mark one.

```
# Edit a bunch of files
vim file1.txt
vim file2.txt
vim file3.txt

# Only mark one of them as going it your next commit
git add file2.txt

# Commit it to history
git commit -m "fixed typo"
```

Note that the changes to file1.txt are *not* yet saved to the repository and file3.txt is not tracked at all yet. You can see that a previously tracked file has unstaged changes by running `git status` and what those changes are by running `git diff`. It this point status would tell you that you have made changes to file1.txt and that there are there is an untracked file3.txt in your directory. Diff would show you the changes you made to file1.txt since the last time you staged and commited it.

One 'gotcha' that you should be warned about starting out so it doesn't bite you down the road is that – because git's concept of a repository is a whole directory and the changes to files are seen as an image of that directory at a point in time – you should consider having separate repositories for disparate projects. Rather than making a single repository out of "My Documents", you should make separate repositories out of directories that contain some meaningful subset of your documents, whether per-topic or per-format or per-project or whatever. This will make it easier down the road when you want to work with "all documents related to x" from another machine without having to have every document you've ever created on that machine. Git does *not allow* you to checkout a subtree of a repository*, it is all or nothing, so err  on the side of making many granular repositories for closely related data sets, one per directory.

Really that's all there is to basic usage. From there, almost anything you can imagine to do is possible, but at that point you would be asking a usage question, not a software recommendation question.

<sub>* Subversion for example did allow this and I got used to it. This bit me early on when I assumed git would allow something similar. I had ALL my personal files in one large svn repo and naively assumed git would be a drop in replacement for that. Lesson learned, and my files are the better off for being categorized.</sub>

#### But command prompts are scary!

There are, of course, a multitude of front end GUIs available to keep you off the command line and visually represent what is going on with your files. Many of these have an IDE-ish flavor to them and might serve as your entry point into document management, using them to launch your favorite editor* or even use a built in one. Since you asked about the back-end about how your files should be stored, I have made a recommendation to use `git` as the version manger, but if you have in mind a way this should look and work from a front end perspective, you should ask that as a separate question.

<sub>* Of course `gvim` would be well suited for this use case ;-)</sub>

#### In conclusion:

Come on in, the water is fine!

One! Two! Three! <strike>Jump</strike> `git init`.

See that wasn't so hard.

Comment: +1. Especially enjoyed the thin sense of humor and the vast comprehensiveness. Good job!

Comment: **Author's Note:** This is currently incomplete, lets call it a draft answer. I still need to address the issues of "simple doing of ___" from the original question and this will likely involve showing why git will handle those cases better than other back-ends, pointing to other documentation for the command line, and suggesting a GUI that makes those functions point and click, but I ran out of time.

Comment: Indeed, it is still _a short one_, but I think the answer clears up the point well enough and addresses the concerns of the OP. A comparison to other tools is a good addition though. Still, it is up to the OP to decide if he'll adopt git and the latter will definitely help with the decision.

Comment: @Caleb : "If you knew any more, you wouldn't even be asking this question." But I don't! And I did! And now reading - thanks for the time you took over it. This could prove very useful.

Comment: @Davïd ... which is why I thought the question was ready to get an answer rather than being closed pending clarification :)

Comment: I don't want to stray off-topic too much, but I disagree with your assessment of CVS vs RCS. IME CVS is easier to get started with than RCS, and it's less of a dead end. But I wouldn't recommend it to anyone starting today: DCVS is the way to go. I like this answer, but you punt the slippery part: picking a DCVS. I'm also disappointed that you don't mention SCCS in your footnote.

Comment: @Gilles I really didn't want to open the can of worms that is CVS. It has some advantages even over upstarts like Subversion and for some things is simpler than RCS. I chose to expound on RCS only because I could reasonably over-simplify it as a contrast to  how `git` works on a conceptual level that I thought was an important contrast for somebody just starting out. And yes, I played dodge-ball on _which_ DVCS to use. A second answer or new section here dealing with which one matches this case might be in order, but I don't know Mercurial well enough to do it justice. SCSS was before my time!

Comment: git really isn't as scary as it sounds. Bazzar on the other hand.. well anyway.

Comment: The downside of SVN allowing changes on a single sub-directory was when we had someone branch a part of a code tree that did not include **all** of the dependencies of that code, we were never able to re-create his release candidate build.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise in this case using https://draftin.com/, see [here](https://draftin.com/documents/229521?mode=presentation&token=oFXCxp0u1FhdU5qoFrVKGD8dYEIFFudSr8QeYzBZNtfGMMYRz8Ed5f-mWrp0q4Ygl6f40iWWWPm_nkWI6-COjSk#0) for a quick look at the specific functionalities you may wish to use.

One downside to this software I want to point out before giving a detailed answer to your question is that it's meant to be used online. It is possible to use draft without an Internet connection (see [over here](http://ninjasandrobots.com/draft-announcements-offline-access)) but it still needs polishing - syncing, which is an essential feature in draft, still has to be triggered by hand before going offline.

1. Version control: **YES**, definitely. It is a core feature in draft, and it's great as it doesn't stand in the way when you don't want to see it, but it is there to serve you each time you - or anyone you share your writing with - mess up with the document. (By default, other's edit are not included in your versions of the document, you have to accept them before.)
2. Ubuntu/Mint friendly: **YES**, it's a website after all. Any decend browser will do the trick, I've tested the offline feature only on chromium, which has a PPA for Ubuntu.
3. Easy tagging/commenting/labelling: **NO**. The point is that draft should handle this for you, by allowing you to mark major and minor versions of your documents, and making clear who did the edits. On this point, draft wouldn't be the best tool for you.
4. Simple tag/label browsing, searching: **not sure**. Well, if the tags draft sets for you suits your needs, at least.
5. Simple "recovery" of previous versions: **YES**. Not only can you recover previous versions, but you can also keep the useful bits in both versions, and edit the current version while viewing the diff with any other version(s).
6. possibility of doing diffs: **YES**. The thing sometimes gets mistaken (the most annoying case would be when rewriting a paragraph : draftin believes I replace every sentence by a new one, mixing the old and the new in the diff, when I would prefer the new paragraph to be separated from the old, but the color codes make it less horrible to deal with.) Diffs work fine, though.
7. possibility of syncing to different machines: **YES**, due to the webpage nature of the thing. The offline mode is weird, though, and necessitates manual syncing.
8. simple directory structure/hierarchy for docs: **YES, but**, a bit too simple even. You can put documents in folder, but I am yet to find a way to nest folders, which is a big downside.

To sum up, draft imposes its way on users, which is cool if you like it (I love it). It sure deserves a try in your case, but its very low flexibility (it does provide an API though, if you're into coding) could limit its scope.

Comment: Helpful reply (and you probably have enough rep to edit your answer with links, if you like). Appreciated especially your pointing out "flaws" (e.g., #8), though they aren't "fatal". One think I could *not* seem to find: is there a cost involved? Seems to be implied by Privacy & ToS, but cannot find any other info.

Comment: I use it for free, with no limits whatsoever. On opening the webpage, a small message is displayed (everytime) to have me remembering that I could support the dev, and giving the two ways you can pay; 

 1. A monthly/yearly subscription.

 2. A one-time purchase of a Gift for you or a friend.

Gifts being reviews by writers, intended to help you on a specific peace of writing.

Answer (score 1):

### Use “[Fossil](https://www.fossil-scm.org/)”

@Caleb's superb [work of supererogation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1495) (above) still makes sense, and compelling reading, years after his having posted it.

However, having worked for seven years to get a system I love, I have found it in [Fossil](https://www.fossil-scm.org/). It has come up [once](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1711) or [twice](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/53609) in SoftwareRecs, but tends to fly under the radar (IMO).

For this user, Fossil answers to all the benefits that Caleb documented regarding a Git-based system, and adds a couple benefits *for my brain/work "habits"*. And it answers beautifully to my original use-case/criteria (of course):

- [image: Yes] version control (essential, obviously!)
- [image: Yes] Ubuntu/Mint friendly (PPA would be great) | **but no PPA needed!**
- [image: Yes] easy tagging/commenting/labelling of "commits"
- [image: Yes] simple tag/label browsing
- [image: Yes] simple tag/label searching
- [image: Yes] simple "recovery" of previous versions
- [image: Yes] possibility of doing diffs
- [image: Yes] possibility of syncing to different machines
- [image: Yes] simple directory structure/hierarchy for docs

### Additional Benefits

There are essentially two benefits *for me* — (n.b. experienced Git users will not be impressed by these):

1. Fossil is *easily* **self-hosted**. This might also be [true of Git](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/867/self-hosted-replacement-for-github), but it seems to me that Fossil can be more simply self-hosted than Git. `<shrug/>` Although this one not one of my essential criteria from my original post, I have come to favour this approach (i.e. not relying on third party services).
2. While the processes are [very similar to Git](https://www.fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/fossil-v-git.wiki), Fossil's approach (again) seems to me to be that bit more streamlined (or simple) so that some of the angst I've experienced in using Git over the years (as I have) is a non-issue.
3. Bonus! It is also very simple to use across platforms (I regularly move between Ubuntu and MacOS); again, Git can of course be used on any platform too, but the bar for entry seems a bit higher on non-Linux systems for Git than it does for Fossil.
4. Bonus 2! Fossil [has been described](https://www.fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/fossil-v-git.wiki#features) as "GitHub-in-a-box", since its single executable file (easily installed in Win/MacOS/*nix systems) includes not only version control, but also issue tracking, wiki, forum, a "chat" like facility, *and* a built-in web frontend ... all in one. Joyous! (Not that one needs to use those extra features, but they're there at no extra cost, as it were.)

Caleb's (surely!) tongue-in-cheek remark about Fossil (among others) ("Your names <s>will never be forgotten</s> are already just a memory.") is unlikely to be the case for Fossil ... it is what manages SQLite development, so not going to go away anytime soon! `:)`

Comment: Wow, my mistake on Fossil. The entire point of the way I classified systems was to recommend *distributed* (DVCS) systems while saying non-distributed VCS systems were based on a restrictive design principle rendered them inherently antiquated. Fossil did not belong in that group when I wrote it and I'm sorry if that delayed your finding a suitable tool.

Comment: @Caleb - Au contraire! Your post convinced me that a DVCS was the only way to go. It's just that, despite using Git fairly regularly (if intermittently) over the years, I've never felt fully comfortable using it. I ran [across](https://corecursive.com/066-sqlite-with-richard-hipp/#building-fossil) Fossil *[almost](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/geek-of-the-week/dr-richard-hipp-geek-of-the-week/)* by [accident](https://www.sqlite.org/codeofethics.html), never (I'm afraid) having registered it from your "soon to be forgotten" list. ;) It's all good, and I remain grateful. :D

Answer (score 0):

git is good solution to version control. Special for plaintext.

- Investigate version control system support integrated in ReText. (I can't find )
- Try git front-ends. I like git-cola.
- Try external diff/merge tools. I like Meld.