# Translation collaboration software for writing articles

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, translation, workflow

We are interested in translating articles (meaning long paragraphed text) from our language to a few of the more widely used languages in Europe.

To that end, I was looking for a way to do the following:

1. Be able to give specific people the ability to collaborate (so login and possibly permissions)
2. Manage the status (pending, worked upon, completed etc) of individual articles per language
3. Collaborate on the translation of the text where people can translate parts of the same article at the same time.
4. Easy to use (not everyone is that good with computers)
5. Preferably free

All of the free solutions I have managed to find so far are oriented torwards app/program string translation.

I was thinking to use something like Trello to do points 1 and 2 and something like Google Docs to do point 3, however that would create an enormous overhead on adding new things and managing them. I think it could get unmanageable quite fast.

I expect that for each language each pool of people would be at most 10 people.

Do you have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered version control software such as `Git`? I'd personally recommend you read [*Simple versioning for plain-text documents (Linux)*](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/simple-versioning-for-plain-text-documents-linux/1495#1495) for more details.

Comment: I read the link you provided. I have trouble understanding how git can help implement a workflow (point 2). Also I feel that version control systems need quite some information to get you started (point 4) maybe some web interface provides a way to use it abstracting the details. Lastly my experience with source control systems so far is that for two people to collaborate on the same file they actually need to spend time and communicate and split up the work (point 3) whereas for example in google docs you see in real time what is happening. If you can give me an example i will give it a try!!

Comment: A russian friend has showed me this site which 'looks' like it would do what I want. Problem being is its in russian! Example a translation from russian to english (left side i think says that you have to be logged in to see original text) http://notabenoid.com/book/49229/203244