# Browser extension for OpenPGP decryption of an e-mail in Gmail

Tags: web-browser, gmail, encryption, pgp

I sometimes received emails on Gmail that people encrypted using my [OpenPGP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.txt) public key. I am looking for a browser extension that can:

- decrypt e-mails in Gmail using my OpenPGP private key (e.g. automatically or by clicking on some "decrypt" button -> I don't want to have to copy-paste somewhere as I currently do)
- work within the Gmail interface (e.g. I don't want to have to POP/IMAP)

and if possible:

- works with Google Chrome and Microsoft Windows 7
- free

Comment: Not a duplicate, but broader: [OpenPGP encryption/decryption of webpage content](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2300/60)

Comment: Well the linked question is indeed boarder in terms of features, but stricter regarding software license and supported browser+OS.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mymail-Crypt for Gmail™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mymail-crypt-for-gmail/jcaobjhdnlpmopmjhijplpjhlplfkhba)

- Integrates with the GMail interface
- You can decrypt e-mails with a "decrypt" button
  [image: test e-mail]
- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- Works with Windows 7
- "This project is no way affiliated with Google™."

  > The project is powered by OpenPGP.js. OpenPGP.js aims to fully implement the RFC 4880 OpenPGP standard. This project is still a work in progress, but supports a variety of key importation/generation abilities to encrypt and decrypt messages. Please see http://openpgpjs.org/ for details on this project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [End-To-End](https://code.google.com/p/end-to-end/):

- open source and free
- developed by Google
- released on [June 3rd, 2014](http://www.wired.com/2014/06/end-to-end/)
- supports RFC 4880 (OpenPGP Message Format) and RFC 6637 (Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) in OpenPGP)
- beware it is in beta and may have security issues
- not available in the Chrome Web Store yet

Comment: According to the linked page it's in alpha, not beta. Not that it makes much difference...

Comment: @nidunc thanks, yes in GMail language beta is when it is ready for the general public :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Pandor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pandor-encrypt-the-conten/ohppeikbgbcloioljhgledibkjdennid):

- it's Free for personal use
- you don't have to handle keys exchange with recipients, they recieve automatically an email with an account
- uses OpenPGP for mail encryption.
- Available in chrome Web Store and works with gmail
- you don't have to copy/paste you text somewhere to encrypt/decrypt.This is done automatilly once connected to your pandor account.