# Browser extension for OpenPGP encryption and decryption of an e-mail in Hotmail

Tags: email, encryption, pgp

It has just been revealed that [Microsoft has sniffed blogger's Hotmail account to trace leak](http://news.cnet.com/8301-10805_3-57620658-75/microsoft-sniffed-bloggers-hotmail-account-to-trace-leak/).

The article says:

> Legally, Microsoft appears to be protected by its privacy policies.
>   The policy for http://Outlook.com, formerly Hotmail, states that, "We
>   may access information about you, including the content of your
>   communications...to protect the rights or property of Microsoft."

Regardless of the legality of Microsoft's actions, I'm looking for a browser extension that can:

- decrypt e-mails in Hotmail  using my OpenPGP private key (e.g. automatically or by clicking on some "decrypt" button -> I don't want to have to copy-paste somewhere as I currently do)
- encrypt using a list of public keys
- work within the Hotmail interface (e.g. I don't want to have to POP/IMAP)

and if possible:

- works with Google Chrome and Microsoft Windows 7
- free

Comment: Related questions: [for Gmail](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2308/60) · [for arbitrary pages](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2300/60)

Comment: I think you might be looking for [WebPG](https://webpg.org/) which is available as a [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpg/hhaopbphlojhnmbomffjcbnllcenbnih) plugin. Other solutions include [Mailvelope](http://www.mailvelope.com/).