# Online email client which supports GPG

Tags: web-apps, email, email-client, pgp

I am looking for an online email client which supports GPG (or PGP). I know it is not suggested for the privacy and safety but for a reason I need it. Do you know any good **online** service for this purpose?

I list what I found, not to duplicate the services that you may want to suggest:

- [Mailpile](https://github.com/mailpile/Mailpile), but I am not sure if it works because its demo doesn't work.
- *G/PGP*, which worked with SquirrelMail but it is out of date and doesn't work with new version of SquireelMail, Ensingia.
- *iGolder*, but it is not really safe.

Comment: Thunderbird + Enigmail is what I use.

Comment: You say you need an "online" client, which would be a Web app, right? But Mailpile is a local client. -- Do you need this Web app to be hosted, or do you want to self-host it?

Comment: Related: [OpenPGP encryption/decryption of webpage content](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2300/6448) and [Browser extension for OpenPGP encryption and decryption of an e-mail in Hotmail](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2589/6448)

Comment: https://posteo.de/en/site/features?