# Netbeans Undo Redo Store Changes

Tags: windows-7, text-editor, ide, gui, netbeans

It's possible to view the changes in code and/or form before to apply them?

I don't turn off Netbeans, but my memory (not computer memory) isn't enough to remember my previous changes....

Then I want to see the Done changes (like Undo button) and changes undone (like Redo button), but if these were stored in some file (like record or log of changes).

Please tell me if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you would be better off switching to a [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) such as:

- [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/),
- [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) or
- [git](http://git-scm.com/).

All 3 are **free**, **cross-platform** and do not **require** a central server or net connection.

You can then commit changes, with a description of the changes **and why they were done** incrementally and be able to review, revert, reapply the changes with some hint to yourself about why they were made.  All of them have tools to let you review the changes between versions.

There are even NetBeans plugins for the last two so you don't even have to switch applications or to the command line.

You will also be better positioned to share/publish your work and when someone says "this bug appeared in version x" you will be well positioned to find out why, *(read up on the bisect tool in any of them)*.

Comment: @chepelucho If you consider this answer (you should), have a read of [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1495/94) which covers the ground on git very well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. It undo (ctrl-Z) and re-do (ctrl-Y) aren't enough for you, then you are saved by NetBeans Local History.

From http://humansky.com/2012/05/netbeans-local-history-to-the-rescue/

> If your IDE doesn’t do local backups, then your changes are lost
>   forever. However, if you use NetBeans IDE, then you should have no
>   problem recovering your lost changes. Ever since NetBeans version 6.x,
>   by default it keeps 7 days work of file changes.
>
> In order to view your file’s local history, make sure the file is open
>   and click Team -> Local History -> Show Local History. NetBeans should
>   give you a diff breakdown of your current file with previous timed
>   snapshots. Once you find the snapshot you want, right click the date
>   and choose Revert from History.

.

See also  http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/netbeans-saved-me-from-my-own-stupidity/2013-02-12

You can compare the current version with any previous version and accept all or individual changes (I am not 100% certain that you can compare two historical version, but why not?).

[image]