# Version-Control for Text Documents - Git based Text-Editor / Markdown-Editor?

Tags: markdown, version-control

We are trying to implement version control for text-documents. Right now multiple people are working undocumented on several copies of documents.

Coming from a programming background I'd like to have only one source of truth and version control.

Since the people working on these documentens have no experience with git the ususal git-workflow via command line or even a gui is too much overhead.

I'm wondering if there is a solution, a text-editor wrapping the git-workflow to make it usable and maintainable by those people, too.

I feel this is a fairly common problem. How did you solve this (possibly using more suitable solutions than git) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple versioning for plain-text documents (Linux)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/simple-versioning-for-plain-text-documents-linux)

Comment: This is really two questions: one about versioning and another about editing. If you narrow down your preferred versioning this could be about collaborative editors. With both ends of the equation open there are an awful lot of possibilities. Also noting your platform, connectedness, and whether you want self hosted or if third party platforms would suit you would make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used google docs to manage collaboration on same presentation quite a few items. This was small scale, about five people typing at same time (we could type and see each other typing as well-could be annoying).

SVN has great merge tools, but only if 'source' based, not too nice in my experience with formatted text.

I have used Jive with Box integration from MS office collaboration. I have not run into any merge conflicts, and it keeps a version for each 'publish' save.  If have time to setup, I think is easy to use for the non geek.

Comment: It's not what OP asked for, but I'm going to second that he/she should really look into Google Docs. In addition to updating in realtime, Google Docs automatically saves a revision history.

Comment: "SVN has great merge tools" is a very 2007 sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Draft? It provides easy version control and collaboration for writers who don't know what a VCS or a terminal at all.

https://draftin.com/

Draft was also discussed here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3300/31569

Answer (score 0):

The Geany editor has a plugin that allows documents to be committed to any of a number of  different version control systems (https://plugins.geany.org/geanyvc.html).  It requires creation of the repository outside the editor and then minimal configuration within the editor.

There are probably other text editors with similar capability either natively or as a plugin (Atom does, I think, though I don't use it myself).