# Very simple open-source task/issues system

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, task-management

I am working together with a group of people and we would like to keep track of our tasks. There are a lot of solutions base on kanban or scrums boards, but we are looking for something very simple but also nice looking and easy to use. Several people in our team are not computer affine and we want to make it as easy as possible to use the task system.

A comment function would be the most important feature. I really do like the Github issue system and would like to have something like that, simply writing a task and then commenting to it in a nice simple interface. And the possibility to add tags and labels and to assign people.

The second important thing is, that most of the work does not happen with the computer, so people should be able to add tasks for example by email. Gitlab issues make this possible, I actually dont know if its possible with Github, too?

Its even very much important, that its a open source software. I was actually already thinking about setting up a Gitea instance and cut everything out except the Issue system. But I hope there is a better way, aside from that, there is no email-to-issue function with gitea. And setting up a Gitlab is even a bigger bomb for a very small problem.

Until now we used Redmine, but the Interface and usability is a catastrophe. If there is a simple Task software that is just like github or gitlab issues, I would love it.

Comment: Just to clarify: open-source and self-hosted is correct – or did I get something wrong? Furthermore, with Github *not* being open source, how does that tag match?

Comment: yes Iam looking for opensource/selfhosted. Github issues is just to show what I would like to have.

Comment: OK, thanks – then I got that right (and the `github` *tag* should rather be removed).

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that GitLab is "too heavy" for your use case? Because GitLab is pretty spot on in the feature requirement of "GitLab-like Issues".

Comment: gitlab is trivial to set up, and runs fine on a $5/mo linode vm (upgrade to $10/mo one for install for the extra RAM - once installed it runs fine on the lower amount).

Comment: @ivanivan Please create an answer about that, please especially demonstrate the easiness of the solution (main steps, maybe with screenshots). Maybe no need to mention Linode, just say that it works on 5$/month hosting maybe? Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to suggest [fossil](https://www.fossil-scm.org) as a lightweight alternative. If it would be my choice, I would configure it as described [here](https://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/doc/trunk/www/custom_ticket.wiki) to add support for assigning tickets to users and would simply use **+foo** identifiers as tags at the end of ticket names. Then searching for tags would become possible by parsing the output of **fossil timeline -t t**

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the open source Drupal 7 based OpenLucius distro:
https://www.drupal.org/project/openlucius

Particularly - Kanban add on module for visual task management:
https://www.drupal.org/project/openlucius_board

Also:
https://www.openproject.org/

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and show how the products you mention meet the requirements? Just pointing to some links isn't considered an answer here (so what you just posted should have been a comment). Please see [our discussion here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for context of what an answer should contain. Thanks!

Comment: both of them are not only simple task or todo tools but full and more complex managing platforms